# How to get a particular month's data from mongodb in node js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs

I've a usecase in which I need to find the data of a particular month. How to get the start and end dates of given month?

Here's the sample code.

```
{"_id":"5e00bc55c31ecc38d023b156","heat":20,"humidity":10,"deviceId":"a-1","template":"13435158964","entryDayTime":"2019-12-23T13:08:37.841Z"},
{"_id":"5e00bbd2c31ecc38d023b155","heat":20,"humidity":10,"deviceId":"a-1","template":"13435158964","entryDayTime":"2019-12-23T13:06:26.366Z"},
{"_id":"5df4a8fb46b9da1e2c0731df","heat":88,"humidity":80,"deviceId":"a-1","template":"13435158964","entryDayTime":"2019-12-14T09:18:51.892Z"},
{"_id":"5e00b50bc127260398cf51dd","heat":20,"humidity":10,"deviceId":"a-1","template":"13435158964","entryDayTime":"2019-12-23T12:37:31.127Z"},
{"_id":"5df20e44e7c51b4bd0095af3","heat":41,"humidity":26,"deviceId":"a-1","template":"13435158964","entryDayTime":"2019-12-12T09:54:12.375Z"}
```

---

**Here's my code without moment.js**

Payload:

```
{
    "deviceId":"a-1",
    "year":2019,
    "month":"December"
}
```

```
Collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
              "deviceId": payload.deviceId,
              "entryDayTime": {
                                $lt: new Date(`${payload.month},${payload.year},2`).toISOString(),
                                $gte: new Date(`${payload.month},${payload.year},31`).toISOString()
                              }
            }
  }
])
```

These are the time ranges I'm getting in console(times passed in aggregate function),

```
2019-12-01T18:30:00.000Z

2019-12-30T18:30:00.000Z
```

**Code with moment.js**

Payload:

```
{
    "deviceId":"a-1",
    "year":2019,
    "month":10
}
```

I've tried with moment.js too. But I'm not getting the times in the format like time format of database.

```
Collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
              "deviceId": payload.deviceId,
              "entryDayTime": {
                 $lt:moment([payload.year]).month(payload.month).startOf('month').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format(),
                 $gte:moment([payload.year]).month(payload.month).endOf('month').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format()
               }
            }
  }
])
```

Following are the timestamps I'm getting in console.

```
2019-11-01T00:00:00+05:30
2019-11-30T23:59:59+05:30
```

If moment.js is preferred, how to change the time format similar to the sample code's time format?

Comment: You want timestamp in this format 2019-12-23T13:08:37.841Z?

Comment: Yes. I want in this format

Comment: I have given the answer , kindly check.

Comment: why haven`t you considered my answer???

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

```
var dated="2019-11-01T00:00:00+05:30";
var newdated= new Date(dated);
var output= newdated.toISOString();
console.log(output);
```

Result :

```
'2019-10-31T18:30:00.000Z'
```

The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended `ISO format (ISO 8601)`, which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively).

The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

Comment: No, I've tried the your answer too. You got me wrong, @Prabhjot Singh Kainth. But I got the same issue. Sorry, if you felt bad. But truly I tried your answer first. The issue is, my database storing timestamps in the following format, ```2019-12-23T06:38:37.841-06:30```.

Answer (score 0):

To find the data of a particular month use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) with the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor to create a range:

```
const payload = {
    "deviceId": "a-1",
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 11 // months start from 0 = January, so 11 = December 
}

const from = new Date(Date.UTC(payload.year, payload.month, 1)).toISOString(); // "2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
const to = new Date(Date.UTC(payload.year, payload.month + 1, 1)).toISOString(); // "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

then use them as follows:

```
Collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
       "deviceId": payload.deviceId,
       "entryDayTime": {
          $lt: to,
          $gte: from
       }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working example** : https://mongoplayground.net/p/jkIJdJ-L7q-

Comment: @Aravind why haven`t you considered my answer at all, may I know the reason?